# enemy shooting towards FPS

Tags: 3d, javascript, vector, first-person-shooter, webgl

WELL first of all I want you to see my game (its deployed on heroku cloud) :

http://still-escarpment-3701.herokuapp.com

(It takes almost 10 sec to load so please wait for couple of sec)

I have successfully implemented fps shooting .but same logic are not working for enemy to fps shooting ..:(

THE PROBLEM IS THAT :

> Bullets gets saturated just after the shooting function is called ..i need enemy to shoot the bullets after some suitable delay just like its happening with fps shooting ...

```
       bulletTempEnemy = new J3D.Transform();

       bulletTempEnemy.geometry = J3D.Primitive.Sphere(0.5, 4, 4);
       bulletTempEnemy.renderer = J3D.BuiltinShaders.fetch("Normal2Color");

       bulletHolderEnemy = new J3D.Transform();

    engine.scene.add(bulletHolderEnemy);



function EnemyShooting(){

     bulletHolderEnemy.position.x =swat2.position.x;
     bulletHolderEnemy.position.y =swat2.position.y;
     bulletHolderEnemy.position.z =swat2.position.z;

    var b = bulletTempEnemy.clone();

var f =v3.sub(first_person_controller.position,swat2.position).norm();
b.direction = new v3(); 
b.direction=f;

    b.position.fromArray(f);
    b.progress = 0;
    b.ttl = 50;

    b.animate = function() {
    b.position = b.direction.cp().mult(1 + b.progress);
    b.progress += 1;
    b.ttl--;            

                if(b.ttl == 0) {
                    bulletHolderEnemy.remove(b);
                                 }
            }

            bulletHolderEnemy.add(b);
```

}

and then code below was called in the game loop function draw()

```
 var zdis= Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.abs(swat2.position.z) -  Math.abs(first_person_controller.position.z)));
 var xdis= Math.abs(Math.abs(Math.abs(swat2.position.x) - Math.abs(first_person_controller.position.x)));


if(xdis < 80)
{
setInterval(EnemyShooting(), 90000);

}



   for(var i = 0; i < bulletHolderEnemy.numChildren; i++) {
   bulletHolderEnemy.childAt(i).animate();
  }
```

library used :J3D (https://github.com/drojdjou/J3D)

any help would be appreciated to resolve this saturation probLem of shooting bullets ....:|

Comment: Generally, if you must include your source code and say "the problem is somewhere in here", the question is too localized. I'm voting to close it as such. Congrats on getting your game as far as you have, but this isn't the place to ask for help debugging your code. See the [FAQ] about where to ask discussion questions and what kind of questions you should ask here.

Comment: I dont want u ppl to debug my code ...i just want to know the idea that need to be implemented?

Comment: Then rewrite your question without a link to your game or any source code, none of that is needed for conceptual level implementation. Describe in words the way you plan on implementing it and what you've tried already.

Comment: Also, if you can't take the time to type "you people" instead of "u ppl" then no one will take you seriously.

Comment: The question is really unclear.

Comment: Anko : i was trying to implement such type of thing in my game :http://icecreamyou.github.com/Nemesis/game.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that I have used for delays: Have a counter that increments by dt each frame. If it is above the required delay, don't continue to increment it. Then, if it is above the required delay AND the firing condition is true, have it fire the bullet and set the counter back to zero.

Pseudo-code here (in game loop):

```
if (firingcounter <= firingdelay){
    firingcounter += dt
}
if (firebulletcondition == true and firingcounter > firingdelay){
    firebullet()
    firingcounter = 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

thankx alot garan my problem is resolved :)

var firingdelay=1000;

var dt=50;

if (xdis < 80 && firingcounter > firingdelay){
    EnemyShooting();
    firingcounter = 0
}

if (firingcounter <= firingdelay){
    firingcounter += dt
}